# group by by considering 4am this day to 4am next day as this day (my SQL)

Tags: mysql

The data base I am querying has 90 days of data  .
I want to get a result where
The day starts from 6/22/2021
eg 4 am (7/1/2021) and ends in 4am (7/2/2021)-this should be considered as 7/1/2021
4am (7/2/2021) to (4am 7/3/2021) as 7/2/2021

Baisically I want to group 4am this day to the next day 4am  so that I can get 90 days of data in 1 go.
I used cast(dateadd(hour,-4).... but it didnt work as there is an overlap from 12 am to 4 am

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 4 hours from the time and then group by date.

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 4 HOURS)) AS date, ...
...
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: yep, and probably want to select it too